# Intel WiFi not working on HP Omen Pro

Tags: wireless, hp, intel

I have a HP Omen Pro and recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and my wifi card 7260 is not working. What can i do ? I have tried everything and searched other forums as well but no solution worked.

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev c3)
 DeviceName: Intel Stone Peak 2 7260 ac 2x2 + BT4 LE Combo Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c070]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi 

0: hci0: Bluetooth 
        Soft blocked: no 
        Hard blocked: no 
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN 
        Soft blocked: yes 
        Hard blocked: no 
2: phy0: Wireless LAN 
        Soft blocked: no 
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. I think the problem is not in 7260 ;-) It works well.

Comment: I have tried it already no luck

Comment: This command does not fix anything it gives information to get a fix.

Comment: i used to have in the past thinkpads and it always worked only this hp wont work kali linux was the only that worked

Answer (score 4):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and your Wi-Fi should work after a reboot.

Comment: nope its not working

Comment: There must be a hardware switch too. Check it. And also check BIOS if it is not disabled there. I see hardblock too.

Comment: WiFi is now working.  I have enabled in bios network boot and it works now. Well maybe just the restart  made it work and it doesnt matter if network boot is enabled or disabled

Comment: My solution did work as `acer_wmi` is a wrong module. You really needed a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `iwlwifi-backports`.
Open terminal and execute following command.

```
sudo apt install iwlwifi-backports
```